# removeObject works, but addObject does not, both have the same parameters

Tags: objective-c

In the following code, removeObject works fine, but addObject does not work. What is wrong?

```
NSMutableArray *sourceList = self.questions;
NSMutableArray *randomizedList;

for (NSInteger i = sourceList.count; i > 0; i--) {
    //other things

    [randomizedList addObject:sourceList[index]];
    [sourceList removeObject:sourceList[index]];
}
```

randomizedList is the same before and after `[randomizedList addObject:sourceList[index]];` is executed: `NSArray > NAObject >isa Class 0x0`

Comment: what error you get ?

Comment: is `randomizedList` mutable array?

Comment: Please show the before and after for `randomizedList`.

Comment: @RonanChaniyara and others: I have edited the question and added the information that was missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `randomizedList` is not allocated.

```
NSMutableArray *sourceList = self.questions;
NSMutableArray *randomizedList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSInteger i = sourceList.count; i > 0; i--) {
    //other things

    [randomizedList addObject:sourceList[index]];
    [sourceList removeObject:sourceList[index]];
}
```